# Cucumber and custom RSpec matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, rspec2, matcher

I'm trying to write a custom RSpec matcher for cucumber. I require cucumber/rails/rspec in env.rb, but I still get "uninitialized constant Spec::Matchers" error. I'm using latest versions of Rspec, Cucumber and CucumberRails. What am I missing?

P.S. Same matcher works fine with pure RSpec...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using RSpec 2? The correct constant is now `RSpec::Matchers` for that. Defined in `rspec/matchers`.

If you're not, then perhaps you haven't required `spec/matchers` which defines the `Spec::Matchers` constant for RSpec < 2.