# uninitialized constant RSpec::Matchers::Composable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a problem running the test case which says `<class:Matcher>': uninitialized constant RSpec::Matchers::Composable (NameError)` after loading so many stuff.Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446338/cucumber-and-custom-rspec-matchers

Comment: do yo have included config.include(Capybara::Webkit::RspecMatchers, :type => :feature) in your rails_helper.rb?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this same issue in my rails app test cases. how i resolved it.

```
follow below two steps:


 1.  first mark the gem as required false  as below
  group 'test' do
     gem 'rspec-sidekiq', require: false
  end
 2. require the gem in rails_helper.rb file as below
     require 'rspec-sidekiq'
```

now problem will be resolved